# Rayleigh Alpine handle bar assembly

Tags: handlebars, headset, new-bicycle-assembly

Hi I recently purchased a [Rayleigh Alpine 4.2 Shimano](https://www.makro.co.za/sports-and-outdoor/raleigh-26-alpine-4-2-mountain-bike-338792EA). I am having a bit of difficulty with assembling the bike. Would anyone be able to assist with fitting the handle bar. I have included pictures of the handle bar stem and the head tube. Thanks for any assistance let me know if any further info is required.

Pic 1 is the bottom of the handlebar with cap on. Pic 2 is the bottom of the handle bar without cap on. Pic 3 is the head set. [[image: Pic 1 is the bottom of the handlebar with cap on.] [image: Pic 2 is the bottom of the handle bar without cap.][image: Pic 3 is the head set where the handle bar fits in]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the other side of the steerer (stem quill) you should have a bolt (most likely with Allen recess) - unscrew this bolt slightly to the wedge (the part that resides on the thread of the bolt) moves away from the steerer. They become more aligned allowing to drive them down the head tube (actually into the fork).

Then tighten the bolt making sure that the handlebars are perpendicular to the weel. The more you tighten the bolt the more the wedge gets stuck in the fork tube. To remove the quill you first unscrew the bolt and then give it a gently tap with a hammer to unseize the wedge.

See the cross-section:

[image]

All of this under the assumption that the diameters of the stem quill and the headset correspond with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Please see my [other post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/rayleigh-alpine-4-2-shimano) regarding the front wheel.

Comment: You're welcome. I did. What kind of problem you have there?

Comment: @Mike If you need to ask for clarifications about the other question, please do it there, rather than here -- John linked his other question. It's very confusing when responses to a particular question get spread around other questions.

Answer (score 1):

The internet is replete with resources for bike assembly and maintenance. Google for instructions for fitting a *quill stem*.