# Raleigh Alpine 4.2 Shimano front wheel and rear brakes assembly

Tags: brakes, wheels, new-bicycle-assembly

Hi I recently purchased a [Raleigh Alpine 4.2 Shimano](https://www.makro.co.za/sports-and-outdoor/raleigh-26-alpine-4-2-mountain-bike-338792EA).

I am having a bit of difficulty with assembling the bike. Would anyone be able to assist with fitting the front wheel. I have included pictures of the right side of the front wheel the left side and the fork of the bike.

With regard to the brakes, it seems that the brake cable fits into a small hole on the silver lever on the left. I don't want to damage anything hence I don't want to apply force. The red and silver cable seems to large to fit into this hole. Does anyone know which part of the cable should be placed in this hole?

Thanks for any assistance let me know if any further info is required.

[image: The right side of the wheel]
[image: The left side of the wheel]
[image: The fork of the bike]
[image: Close up of right side]
[image: Close up of left side]
[image: Rear brakes]

Comment: There is a plastic cap on the wheel axle on the second and the last picture. Also, there is some sort of filler/protector on the fork. Please remove them, have a good look and describe what kind of problem you exactly have.

Comment: Yep, remove the protectors installed to help reduce shipping damage.

Comment: Are there no instructions provided by Raleigh?

Comment: @Mike I managed to sort out the front wheel thanks. Please see if you know which part of the break cable needs to fit into the silver attachment on the left. I want to avoid applying too much force.

Comment: Go look at any bike rack where a bike with V-brakes is stored.  You will see how the cable is fit together.  (Hint:  It's necessary to push the rubber corrugated tube back away from the J-shaped metal tube in order to assemble.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes this is what say show on youtube (pull back the black rubber part). The problem is that the metal hole doesn't reach that far even when I compress the breaks as much as possible.

Comment: Then the brakes need to be adjusted.  (Take it to a bike shop, or to a buddy who knows something about bikes.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Okay thanks, just strange that it needs adjusting even though it is new and just taken out of the box. You can see from the picture that it won't reach.

Comment: An ongoing series of small questions on how does part *a* fit into part *b* is kinda abusing how this site is supposed to work. A more appropriate place is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).

Comment: Re need of adjustment - totally does not surprise me that an inexpensive bike that is shipped disassembled needs adjusting, but [there is a video for that](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/linear-pull-brake-service)

Comment: You'll probably need to adjust the [gear indexing as well](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment)

Comment: @JohnDoe - You seem to be under the mistaken impression that it was all assembled in the first place, then disassembled for shipping.

Answer (score 2):

The internet is replete with resources for bike assembly and maintenance. Park Tool Company has a particularly comprehensive set of articles and YouTube videos.

Wheel axle obviously fits into the slots in the dropouts in the fork, and then the nuts are tightened on the axle. I imagine you need to know if the washers go inside or outside the dropout slots.

Check out [this article](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/wheel-removal-and-installation), look for a section titled "Solid Axle Systems", You can see that the tab washers go outside and fit into a hole in the dropout.

Comment: Thanks yes I managed to fit it based on the article. If you have a chance please see the updated question regarding the rear brakes.

Answer (score 0):

Your other question should really be asked separately.

[image: V Brake setup]

This is how V Brakes should look when assembled.  The rubber Boot will slide to the right, and you will see a hole in the noodle holder that holds the noodle.  It should take a bit of squeezing on the Arms to get it all fitting through.

Once its all assembled, you should be able to squeeze the brake lever up on the bars, and the two arms will lean-in at the same rate, and then pull off at the same rate and offset.  Shouldn't have one arm moving a lot more than the other.  This can be adjusted iteratively with the Spring Tension Screw on the bottom of both brake arms.